# C pointer to another struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

i'm currently reading some source codes for packet sending. For the following pseudo code, for the line "packet->packet2 = (char*) data", what does it mean actually? Can i understand as storing the character datatype in variable data into packet2, which is also defined as a character datatype?

```
struct Node1
{
    char packet1;
    int num1;
}

struct Node2
{
   char *packet2;
   int num2;
}

int main(void)
{
   struct Node1 *data;
   struct Node1 var1;

   struct Node2 *packet;
   struct node2 var2;

   data = &var1;
   packet = &var2;

   packet->packet2 = (char*) data;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile. Fix it.

Comment: In fact, there is no `packet2` field in `packet` variable because is `Node1` type

Comment: Even if it compiles, it'll be plain wrong. You cannot put a pointer into a `char`.

Comment: i mixed up the Node1 and Node2 variables but i've fixed it as per above.

Comment: You have not allocated memory for `packet`

Comment: first allocate memory for packet dynamically

Comment: @achal why dynamically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not the programming question, only lack of the basic knowledge of the C language

Comment: This is question is unclear, what is your specific problem ? And OP obviously don't know a bit of C.

Answer (score 0):

packet2 is of type char you can not put a pointer in to this field of the structure.Char variable can't hold a pointer.You have to change packet2 from type char to type char*.
This will mean that you can use each byte separately since dereferencing a char poiner gives you a byte.

```
packet2[0]
```

will give you acces to the first byte of the var1 structure.
It's important to note that when you are doing such things you have to be very careful becouse there might be padding bytes.For such cases you can use the macro offsetof.

```
packet->packet2[0] = 5;
```

will be equivalent to

```
var1.packet1 = 5;
```

Comment: i see. So if i changed packet2 to type char*, what does the line "packet->packet2 = (char*) data means?

Comment: it will mean packet2  will point to struct Node1 *data. packet2[0] will give you first byte of the structure etc..but it's important to note theres padding

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node1
{
    Node2*/or Node1*.... packet1;
    int num1;
}

struct Node2
{
   Node1* packet2;
   int num2;
}

int main(void)
{
   struct Node1 *data;
   struct Node1 var1;

   struct Node2 *packet;
   struct Node2 var2;

   data = &var1;
   packet = &var2;

   packet->packet2 =  data;
}
```